# Tesseract error: symbol lookup error: tesseract: undefined symbol: _ZN10SIMDDetect14avx_available_E

Tags: tesseract, ubuntu-18.04

Recently, tesseract started throwing errors on our EC2 instance (Ubuntu 18.04) and I decided to re-install tesseract-ocr altogether.

To uninstall existing tesseract version:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tesseract-ocr
```

To install tesseract, I tried:

```
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev liblept5
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y
```

But now, when I run

```
tesseract -v
```

It returns:
tesseract: symbol lookup error: tesseract: undefined symbol: _ZN10SIMDDetect14avx_available_E

I'd appreciate any help to fix this issue!